# Orchard CMS - Enumerate menus

Tags: orchardcms

I installed the Advanced menu - version 1.4.1 module.

What I'm trying to do is to build my own menu template. I think by default, menu was rendered using unordered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternates. 
Just copy the existing `Menu.cshtml` (to override the menu rendering) and/or `MenuItem.cshtml` (to override the menu item rendering) files from Module /Views folder to /Views folder of your theme. After copying, change the markup in those files at your desire.

Comment: Where on earth is DisplayChildren() method??

Comment: found it src\Orchard\Mvc\ViewEngines\Razor\WebViewPage.cs